# setuptools: testing my extras

Tags: python, testing, setuptools, python-unittest

I'd like to support an interface where a new dev just needs to run `python setup.py test` to run all my tests. I think that's reasonable.

Given that I have several "extras" defined in my package ([optional features with their own dependencies](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)), how do I make sure the tests for these run correctly under `python setup.py test`.

Is this too much to hope for?

For example, I tried adding `.[extra-feature-1]` to my tests_require list, but that was obviously wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure extras are installed when running tests you use the `--extras` argument when running `setup.py`.

you can add default options for `setup.py` using the `setup.cfg` file.

e.g. in `setup.cfg` add:

```
[test]
extras=1
```

or if you use `pytest`:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
[pytest]
extras=1
```

with this, running `python setup.py test` will automatically add `--extras` to the command

Comment: "'test' has no such option 'extras'"